# Remote access my desktop through router

Tags: android, remote-desktop, firewall, remote-access, tablet

How can I remote access my computer desktop that is behind a router with my Android Tablet?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way:

1) Download Teamviewer (free for non-commercial use) for linux at http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx?os=linux

2) Download Teamviewer for Android from [market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile&rdid=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile&rdot=1)

3) Open it on your PC, and it will give you an ID and a Password:

[image]

4) Open it on your Tablet, and paste the ID and Password:

[image]

then click "Connect to partner".

5) Enjoy ;-)

ps.: when installing teamviewer on my Ubuntu 64 bits I got a dependency error (*) that was solved by installing wine before trying to install teamviewer (`sudo apt-get install wine`).

(*)

```
 
 teamviewer6 depends on libc6-i386 (>= 2.7); however:
  Package libc6-i386 is not installed.
 teamviewer6 depends on lib32asound2; however:
  Package lib32asound2 is not installed.
 teamviewer6 depends on lib32z1; however:
  Package lib32z1 is not installed.
 teamviewer6 depends on ia32-libs; however:
  Package ia32-libs is not installed.
```